# Drupal Node Render: load full page (scripts, head...everything)

Tags: drupal

I have a module I am putting together and am using this code to programatically load a node and get its markup:

```
<?php
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node_view = node_view($node, 'full');
  $rendered_node = drupal_render($node_view);
  echo $rendered_node;
?>
```

However...whilst it gives me the themed output of a node (the markup from the node content itself, not the page and html template information that would be loaded for that instance of the node) it does not give me all the information I want. I would really like to get the full output of what the entire themed page would be which includes the HTML tags, HEAD tag and all the content.

Ultimately, I would really like to get the standard variables structure that would be present for each node I load in this way, but would be happy to settle for final markup (at least this will be guaranteed to be post any processing by modules etc). I am of course loading a node programatically that might not be the current node being processed by the page that is currently using the module, so to my mind I am currently unable to get the information that I require.

Is this possible? Much obliged for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about it this way:

```
$my_page_callback_result = menu_execute_active_handler("node/$nid", false);
```

Have a look at this array, it contains lots of variables, hopefully the ones you need.
Additionaly, you can do the following to get the fully rendered html page:

```
$my_full_html = drupal_deliver_html_page($my_page_callback_result);
```

Both of these functions are documented here:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/7

Greets

Comment: Thanks! Believe it or not I was trying to do this but hadn't got it to work yet. It seems when I call 'drupal_deliver_html_page' it sends the data via HTTP and I get all the content loaded onto the page...need to look at simply getting the info that I want sandboxed inside a variable...thanks though you are leading me down a good path!

Comment: This has done the trick, currently returns a string:
    drupal_render_page($page)